# How to avoid hiding section that shouldn't hide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/citiel/4gsgY/) of what I've got until now.

What I'm trying to reach is to have a list of info hidden just to be shown whenever you click on it.

It all consists on a `ul` list with `ul` children nested inside of its `li` elements and so.

Until now it does what it should: Hides or shows the `ul` child when you click on a `li` parent.

But the problem is that when I click on a `li` inside a `ul` which is already inside a `li`, this parent `ul` hides.

How can I avoid this to happen? Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm not really that new to js but I'm still learning and I would like to see what you, guys, can teach me.

Thanks in advance.

**PD**: If it is not too much to ask, I would really a appreciate a pure js answer so I can learn more of it (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue arrises from event propagation.  What was happening in your fiddle was that when the child was clicked the event was also propagating to the parent and hiding the whole thing.  Thats why you might notice that the second time the parent li was opened the child would be open also.  [Here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) is a link to an explanation of the different ways events propagate in different browsers.

For everything but IE version <9. [This modification to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gsgY/1/) should make your code work.  The only difference being that I am stopping the event from propagating from your child li to the parent li, with

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Check out Mozilla's [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="clpsble-area">
    <ul onclick="clpsble(event)">
        <li class="collapser">Rand Stuff 1
            <div class="clpsble-sec hide">
                <ul>
                    <li class="collapser">Rand Stuff 1.1
                        <div class="clpsble-sec hide">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Rand Stuff 1.1.1</li>
                                <li class="collapser">Rand Stuff 1.1.2
                                    <div class="clpsble-sec hide">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Rand Stuff 1.1.2.1</li>
                                            <li>Rand Stuff 1.1.2.2</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rand Stuff 1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>Rand Stuff 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function clpsble(e){
      for(el in e.target.children)el.style.display=el.style.display==='hidden'?'block:'hidden';
    }
</script>
```